Bicep for creating API connection for SQL over Data Gateway
I'm trying to automate deployment of my Azure integration project using bicep. The projects includes a Logic App, which connects to an on-prem sql database unsing an on-premise data gateway. This requires creating an Api Connection for the Logic App. However, exact parameters for the API connection are not documented at all and cannot be exported from the UI. I found similar thread for Arm, not bicep, and gave the following code a try:
resource apiConnection 'Microsoft.Web/connections@2018-07-01-preview' = {
  name: apiConnectionName
  location: 'westeurope'
  kind: 'v2'
  properties: {
     alternativeParameterValues: {}
     api: {
       id: subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis', location, 'sql')
       type: 'Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis'
     }
     displayName: apiConnectionName
     parameterValues: {
        Server: 'sqlservername'
        Database: 'dbname'
        AuthType: 'WindowsAuthentication'
        username: 'user-id'    
        password: 'user password'
        gateway: {
           id: '/subscriptions/<subid>/resourceGroups/<rg-name>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connectionGateways/<gateway-name>'
        }  
     }     
     customParameterValues: {}
 }}

When I run the code above, I'm getting the following error:

The connection gateway installation
'/subscriptions/SUB_ID/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/northeurope/connectionGatewayInstallations/SOME_GUID'
cannot be referenced as it is already linked with the connection
gateway
'/subscriptions/SUB_ID/resourceGroups/RG_NAME/providers/Microsoft.Web/connectionGateways/GATEWAY_NAME'.
Connection gateway installation can only be linked with a single
connection gateway at a time. (Code:
ConnectionGatewayInstallationUnavailable)

The error makes little sense, as I'm only trying to create a new API connection referencing existing data gateway.
Have anyone got that working with bicep? Maybe this is documented somewhere?

do you have any other Microsoft.Web/connections using this gateway ? I think the error message is saying you can only have one connection per gateway so you would need to reuse the existing connection if you have alreayd one

From what I understand the message says you can only link 1 gateway to 1 onprem installation.


The connection gateway installation '/subscriptions/SUbB_ID/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/northeurope/connectionGatewayInstallations/SOME_GUID' cannot be referenced as it is already linked with the connection gateway:

The error comes when there is an already existed connection per gateway, you need to use the existing connection again if you have already one as @Thomas also mentioned and you cannot be able to reference it in another API connection.
As a workaround, you can try below approaches listed.
you can remove the api block as it is not required in accessing and connecting the on-premises connectors.
And also check the gateway ID again and make sure that you are passing it correctly in your bicep code.
If still the issue persists, try creating a new SQL on-premise gateway with the same existing configuration and reference it in the code.
I tried below code in my environment which is similar as you and was able to connect to on-premise as shown.
param apiConnectionName string = 'connnamejah'
param location string = 'westeurope'
param sqlServerName string = 'newserverj'
param sqlDatabaseName string = 'dbjah'
param username string = 'roots'
param password string = 'xxx'
param gatewayId string = 'xxxx'

resource apiConnection 'Microsoft.Web/connections@2016-06-01' = {
  name: apiConnectionName
  location: location
  properties: {
    //alternativeParameterValues: {}
    api: {
      id: subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis', location, 'sql')
      type: 'Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis'
    }
    displayName: apiConnectionName
    parameterValues: {
      server: sqlServerName
      database: sqlDatabaseName
      authType: 'WindowsAuthentication'
      username: username
      password: password
      gateway: {
        id: gatewayId
      }
  }
}
}

Output:


